# Visual Studio 2015 broken: [Failure] Could not find file v4.6.AssemblyAttributes.cs

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I was trying to install VS 2017 RC, but the installation failed due to insufficient disk space. I've aborted the installation and clicked "Remove" in the installer to remove VS2017 that didn't finish installing.

Now when I try to open any type of project in VS2015 (which I kept), the projects fail to load and I get this error:

> [Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Users\darkstar\AppData\Local\Temp.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.AssemblyAttributes.cs'.

What can possible cause this or how can this be fixed?

(I tried reinstalling VS 2015 - didn't help)

Comment: Rebuilding the project fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you break away from source control? I did with my application and then tried opening a local instance of the version when this error appeared.  It could be unrelated though and I may have produced this error at an earlier time in my development.

I cleaned and rebuilt my solution.  Then I went to the menu and selected File > Source Control > Add to source control.  Then I re-loaded VS2015 and my error was resolved.